# Sapply is not working like for loop

Tags: r

```
sapply(c(2:5), function(y){
x[y,]<-x[y,]-(x[1,]*x[y, 1]/x[1, 1])})

for (i in c(2:5)){
  x[i,]<-x[i,]-(x[1,]*x[i, 1]/x[1,1])}
```

Can someone explain to me why I am getting different results, I am coming from Python, and I am not used to these applied functions of R

Comment: I get the same result from both pieces of code.  Both give error messages. You need to tell us what `x` is.

Comment: X is a 5x5 matrix; I realized later that Sapply takes the rows and puts them as columns that is why I was getting different results. Thanks for your reply!